# hide/show column not working for datatable-colvis-basic using angular js

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I am trying to hide/show columns class datatable-colvis-basic but it is hiding only the table header not data. I think because my dynamic table data from angular js. what is solution for that.

```html
     <table id="table_id" class="table datatable-colvis-basic" id="DataTables_Table_0 " role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info" ng-show="numberLoad">
                <thead>
                    <tr> 
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Order Id</th>
                        <th>SKU</th>
                        <th>Vendor Name</th>
                        <th>Recived MP</th>
                        <th>Placed On MP</th>
                        <th>Placed On Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <tr dir-paginate="mplist in getMpList |  itemsPerPage:mpreportinfo.itemsPerPage" current-page="mpreportinfo.currentPage" total-items="total_count">
                        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                        <td>{{mplist.order_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{mplist.sku}}</td>
                        <td>{{mplist.vendor_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{mplist.order_source_name}}</td>
                        <td>Amazon</td>
                        <td>{{mplist.placed_date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

[please check attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLyIL.jpg)

Comment: Your `ng-show` is on the table element, not the class. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes, because if data fully loaded then its show using ng-show

Comment: by removing ng-show  getting same issue @KfirM

Comment: What is `numberLoad`? does putting `ng-show="false"` works (hides the entire table)? 
I can't figure out much from the image you provided. Maybe you could ass some sketch on top of it. And why you wrote `datatable-colvis-basic` in your question when you are relating to the table element and not the class?

Comment: before data load numberLoad is false after getting data numberLoad set to true, datatable-colvis-basic class use for hide/show columns which is inbuilt of theme @KfirM

Comment: does doing `ng-show="false"` work? Could you post the code which changes  `numberLoad` ? Have you tried `ng-if`?

Comment: how can i use for ng-if there mean how it will work, am new to anguler js. so will this issue resolve?

Comment: <tr dir-paginate="mplist in getMpList |  itemsPerPage:mpreportinfo.itemsPerPage" current-page="mpreportinfo.currentPage" total-items="total_count"> i think issue with this line because i used static data in simple <tr><td> its working for that

Comment: when ng-show is false it should hide the entire data. So it's not related to the <tr> in the table body. The image you attached looks to me like ng-show value is true. but no items in getMpList ....

Answer (score 0):

Put the ng-show in the element inside the table.

```
<table id="table_id" class="table datatable-colvis-basic" id="DataTables_Table_0 " role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Order Id</th>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>Vendor Name</th>
                    <th>Recived MP</th>
                    <th ng-show="numberLoad">Placed On MP</th>
                    <th>Placed On Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr dir-paginate="mplist in getMpList |  itemsPerPage:mpreportinfo.itemsPerPage" current-page="mpreportinfo.currentPage" total-items="total_count">
                    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                    <td>{{mplist.order_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{mplist.sku}}</td>
                    <td>{{mplist.vendor_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{mplist.order_source_name}}</td>
                    <td ng-show="numberLoad">Amazon</td>
                    <td>{{mplist.placed_date}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here you have an example of show or hide columns with angularJS and ng-show.
I hope it helps you.
https://codepen.io/salva341/pen/oqyxKW